# Is it possible to change the style of an element when a specific div/element is scrolled into view?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Specifically, I want to change colors of sticky and fixed elements on my page dynamically as the user scrolls into specific sections. I know that this is possible with the pixel height on scroll, but I can't use this technique, because the background of my page consists of a stack of images. This causes the pixel height of the page to change dramatically on window resize due to the height needing to increase as the image gets wider
.

I guess it would be possible to do this with a bunch of media calls, but I'm trying to avoid this, and I'm not even sure it would work.

My main goal would be: 
When a div is scrolled into view, the style (mainly color and font-weight) of the navigation bar and fixed footer change.

Also - This has to be in Vanilla JS.

If someone has a pure CSS solution, that's very acceptable as well, I just can't think of a way this would work.

Thank you!

Comment: `if(Element.scrollTop === number){otherElement.className = 'yourOldClass someClass'}`. CSS should be used for style.

Comment: @StackSlave Would the 'number' variable you wrote in work? If you read my question, the pixel height changes based on screen width. So I can't use pixels. I was thinking potentially I could use percentages of screen height... ?

Comment: It needs to be a Number.  You could use use something like `if(element.scrollTop >= eventObject.clientY-getBoundingClientRect(elementYouWantToSeeTopOf).top)`. Note `eventObject` is passed to your eventListener.

Comment: @StackSlave is this jQuery?

Comment: No, and `element.` and the like are generic. You can get Elements a bunch of different ways, including `document.getElementById('html_id_here')` or `document.querySelector('#html_id_here')`. The later works like jQuery, but is not. I would only use jQuery these days if you're doing animations or something that cannot easily be done with Vanilla JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

How About Using This?

These are VanillaJS SpyScroll

https://github.com/cferdinandi/gumshoe

https://github.com/ederssouza/vanillajs-scrollspy

From Codepen zchee/pen/ogzvZZ

HTML

```
  <div class="m1 menu">
    <div id="menu-center">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="home" class="section"></div>
  <div id="portfolio" class="section"></div>
  <div id="about" class="section"></div>
  <div id="contact" class="section"></div>
```

SCSS

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.light-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(4, 180, 49, 0.6);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

#menu-center {
  width: 980px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  ul {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
    li {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0 30px 0 0;
      display: inline;
    }
  }
}

.active {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

a {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#home {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#portfolio {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#about {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
  var sections = {};
  var i = 0;

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(section, function(e) {
    sections[e.id] = e.offsetTop;
  });

  window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

    for (i in sections) {
      if (sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
        document.querySelector('.active').setAttribute('class', ' ');
        document.querySelector('a[href*=' + i + ']').setAttribute('class', 'active');
      }
    }
  };
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! That looks great, but I can't use any external packages, it's a company's internal server, and things like that would need to go through a long process to be approved